# How to use non ARC framework in ARC iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I saw some replies to exact question. Most replies asking to include "-fno-objc-arc".

Let me try to explain the issue.

I have a framework "MobileCommunicationLibrary.framework" which uses lot of non ARC stuff like 1) class which subclass NSAutoReleasePool 2) uses retain, release

This framework has a headerfile "MobileCommunicationLibrary.h" which I need to import in the ARC application and lot of other headerfiles which MobileCommunicationLibrary.h has dependency like "VNSAutoReleasePool.

Now I am developing an iOS application "TestIQLNative". This has class "AppDelegate.h" and  "AppDelegate.m" which uses ARC stuff like weak property and synthesizing it. This class has to use ARC compiling or compiler flag has to be "-fobjc-arc"

Also, I need to import <MobileCommunicationLibrary/MobileCommunicationLibrary.h> to AppDelegate.h to use methods provided by the framework.

When I import I am getting lot of errors related to retain, release, NSAutoReleasePool etc as they are non ARC.

I wont be able to put "-fno-objc-arc" for AppDelegate.m as that would give error complaining synthesizing weak property allowed only in ARC.

Can someone help?

< Errors and my Build phase >

[image: Error and my compile source screenshot]

< One of the errors in the header file which uses non ARC code in header files >

[image: One of the errors in the header file which uses non ARC code in header files]

< Framework header files and including one header file in Appdelegate.h >

[image: Framework header files and including one header file in Appdelegate.h]

<  Framework Header file required by application >

[image: Framework Header file required by application]

Comment: Show the specific errors and the code that causes them. Header files should not need to have anything which can't be compiled either with or without ARC. For example, you have no idea whether Foundation or UIKit is built with or without ARC. It has almost certainly changed over time. But that causes no problems. Neither should this.

Comment: @KenThomases  I have added some screenshots. Are you able to view it? I should not be editing the header files of the framework

Comment: Just throwing this out there… why not use the automatic refactoring tool to convert your non-ARC library to ARC?

Comment: I should not edit framework. It is provided  by 3rd party. And again ARC conversion tool will not be able to convert these. It will ask to fix these errors in VNSAutoReleasePool manually

Comment: Rather than importing the umbrella header (MobileCommunicationLibrary/MobileCommunicationLibrary.h) for the framework, can you import the individual headers for the classes that you actually need? The one that uses `NSAutoreleasePool` doesn't look like anything that should be used by clients of the library. It looks like part of the implementation. Just avoid importing it, if you can. If you can't, you may be able to hack something by doing `#define NSAutoreleasePool NSObject` before importing it.

Comment: That is the only class I require. It contains all the methods that I have to use in the application. Can you please give detail of what you meant by "#define NSAutoreleasePool NSObject before importing it"?

Comment: This framework works perfectly fine when used in a test application, where I can turn off ARC

Comment: *What* is the only class you require? You show a header that declares `ObjectAutoreleasePool` and `TraceObjectAutoreleasePool` as well as a category on `NSAutoreleasePool`. If you're using ARC then you surely don't require those classes. If you put the line `#define NSAutoreleasePool NSObject` just before the line `#import <MobileCommunicationLibrary/MobileCommunicationLibrary.h>`, then you will effectively change the declarations so they no longer refer to `NSAutoreleasePool`. The macro will substitute `NSObject` instead. It's a gross hack, but you don't have much choice.

Comment: I meant MobileCommunicationLibrary/MobileCommunicationLibrary.h is the only class the application needs to know, which has all methods. Adding screenshot

Comment: MobileCommunicationLibrary/MobileCommunicationLibrary.h is not a class, it's a header file. It evidently contains the declaration of a class, but I see nothing in that declaration that should run afoul of ARC. What is importing the header file that uses `NSAutoreleasePool`? By the way, when you're posting code, post text not screenshots. Use the code formatting mechanism of StackOverflow's markdown, of course. Also, when you reply to a comment, address the person you're talking to (e.g. @chris_sencha) so they notified of the reply.

Comment: I dont directly use NSAutoReleasePool. Framework is using it. Framework is using VNSAutoReleasePool(had pasted its screenshot earlier). And VNSAutoReleasePool is imported in another framework header VSystem.h and GCCollectable.h. VSystem.h is imported in mhf_MHFMobileApplication.h and that is imported in MobileCommunicationLibrary.h

Answer (score 2):

You don't put that linker flag into the View controller's class, but rather set the flag on the imported library you're using. You accomplish this by:

1. Within Xcode select your project under [TARGETS].
2. Select the [Build Phases] tab.
3. Find the library's header / class files under 'Compile Sources'.
4. Add the compiler flag to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added some screenshots. Are you able to view it? I should not be editing the header files of the framework

Comment: My framework is in Link Binary with Libraries. It is not there in Compile Sources.

Comment: @chris_sencha Can you manually add the header file to [compile sources] with the flag?

Comment: That seems to be not working. So I tried drag and drop headers from framework to Compile Sources and added flag. Still same errors. Next I removed those error giving headers from framework and added directly to project and then to compile source and gave flags. Still same error

Comment: @chris_sencha Which specific framework are you trying to make work?

Comment: Its framework given by our vendor. Applications and the framework used to be Non ARC and it works fine. But now when trying to use same framework in ARC application code, these issues happen.

Comment: @chris_sencha It sounds like your vendor is going to have to provide an updated framework. Maybe someone else will chime in with a workaround, but I'm out of ideas.